# Redirect to custom 404 error page when subpage of any domain not found

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-404

I am using htacces for redirection

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```

By this code i am only able to redirect

```
www.abc.com/sfgsg
```

to **custom error page**.

I want to redirect

```
www.abc.com/services/fsdgg
```

to also on **custom error page**.

or

```
 www.abc.com/product/dsgdfsg
```

to

**custom error page**. How this could be done. Guide

Answer (score 0):

If /services or /product are real folders (as opposed to dynamic uri mapping) you can place folder-specific .htaccess files in each that you want a custom 404 page for. Each .htaccess file would specify what `ErrorDocument` directives are to be followed for that path.

Alternatively, you can have your php code handle the custom mapping. Apache adds the system variables `REDIRECT_URL` and `REDIRECT_STATUS` to allow error pages to figure out where the user tried to go and why they failed to go there. See the [Apache docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/custom-error.html#variables) for exactly how/what it does.